# Is is possible to connect 27" Thunderbolt Display using the Thunderbolt port on the back of the display?

Tags: thunderbolt

Normally you use the non-removable Thunderbolt cable with the MagSafe connector to your computer. However, I think my cable is broken. The display flickered on once and then died a few moments later (have been able to repeat this once or twice) and want to rule out the cable the issue.

Is it possible to use a Thunderbolt 1/2 male to male cable to connect to back of the display's Thunderbolt port to drive the display?

I.e Use a cable such as this one:

[image: Ports on the back of the display]

and the connect it to your computer and then plug into the display here:

[image: Ports on the back of the display]

Thunderbolt is supposed to be bidirectional so will this work?

If you've tried it please confirm.

Comment: What's the exact model of your monitor? You should check the monitor's documentation first.

Comment: (this might not be the exact same model) I found a comment on iFixit that says it should work as long as your computer has thunderbolt 1 or 2. PS. the magsafe cable internally just connects to a thunderbolt port as well. https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Apple+Thunderbolt+Display+Thunderbolt+&+MagSafe+Cable+Replacement/112355

Comment: Thanks, I originally got the idea from another comment on iFixit (https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/143647/How+can+I+fix+my+display+blacking+out+intermittently#answer360012). Would like to know if anyone else can confirm that this worked for them?

Comment: Checked the manual, didn't see anything that makes this obvious about doing this. The exact model number is A1407.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this will work fine.

I have two Thunderbolt displays attached to my iMac and one has a frayed cable like yours. I have it daisy-chained to my other display via a normal Thunderbolt cable between the two.

In fact, if you were to take the display apart, you would find that the built-in cable is actually just an ordinary cable plugged into a regular ol’ Thunderbolt port on the logic board. Nothing special about it other than it has the Magsafe power cord bound conveniently to it as well.

Comment: He can't daisy chain it. It is the only monitor he has. So the question is if the regular TB port on the back can be used as input. would you be willing to you test that? Whether that works seems to be impossible to determine from anything I can find on the internet.

Comment: @Tonny; Understood but I was just saying your screen is just like any thunderbolt device; it has two ports on it. Just one is on the inside where you can’t see it. But it doesn’t matter which one you plug into. Both work exactly the same. I don’t have access to my Mac to test right now but I know it will work.

Comment: Thank you! I purchased a Thunderbolt cable and this was indeed the problem. Bonus, I’ve been able to test this with a second Thunderbolt Display and you can actually drive 2x displays by plugging cable from the computer into the back a fully working display, and then plugging it’s cable (the one with the mag safe connector) into the back of another display and both displays work. This does not work when connected via a Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt uses a daisy-chain method for connecting devices, similar to how FireWire and SCSI were implemented in the past.  This means you can link multiple Thunderbolt devices in a chain.

Not all Thunderbolt controllers are made equal.  Their are different versions and implementations.  However, There will be no harm in testing chaining two monitor together to see if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is very unclear if the regular thunderbolt plug at the back can be used as an input.
It is intended as an OUTPUT for daisy-chaining a 2nd Thunderbolt monitor, but it may also be able to be used as an input.

It can't hurt to try.
You can't fry the electronics, it just won't work.
And a male-male TB cable (make sure you get one that handles Thunderbolt V2) is a lot cheaper than a new monitor.
And funny enough... Contrary to anything else Apple makes their official TB cables are actually quite cheap. (About $30-$40, depending on where you live.)

Answer (score 1):

I bought a thunderbolt monitor with a frayed Thunderbolt cable. I bought a Thunderbolt 2 cable (1/2 metre) and Thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter and connected the T/B 3 end into my Mac Mini M2 and the T/2 cable directly into the spare T/B slot on the monitor (btwn Ethernet & FireWire ports) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).